# Spring Boot always using same SPRING-DATASOURCE-USERNAME & SPRING-DATASOURCE-PASSWORD from Azure Key Vault for two separate application

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, azure-keyvault

I have successfully configured one Spring Boot application to use Azure Key Vault. The Key Vault is providing User Name & Password of database. Now when I configured another similar application which connect to a separate database schema hosted on same db url, this time I saved user id and password  with a key name suffixed with "APP2" on same Key Vault.

Strangely Application 2 is somehow connecting to database used by Application 1 which is because its using credentials of Application 1 which is the value of keys  SPRING-DATASOURCE-USERNAME & SPRING-DATASOURCE-PASSWORD

Is there any default spring boot/jps logic to always go for SPRING-DATASOURCE-PASSWORD these key.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: <datasource url>
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    username: "${SPRING-DATASOURCE-USERNAME}"
    password: "${SPRING-DATASOURCE-PASSWORD}"
  cloud:
      azure:
      keyvault:
        secret:
           property-sources[0]:
            credential:
              managed-identity-enabled: true
            endpoint: <key vault url>
```

This is yaml for application 2

```
  spring:
  datasource:
    url: <datasource url>
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    username: "${SPRING-DATASOURCE-USERNAME-APP2}"
    password: "${SPRING-DATASOURCE-PASSWORD-APP2}"
  cloud:
      azure:
      keyvault:
        secret:
           property-sources[0]:
            credential:
              managed-identity-enabled: true
            endpoint: <key vault url>
```

I tried deleting the Application 2 Keys from Key Vault and that application still works and connect to Application 1 datasources. I tried deleting keys used by Application 1 and now both application fails ro start with incorrect user id.password error.

Comment: Spring Cloud Azure, as you configured, will expose a `PropertySource`. As Azure Keyvault doesn't allow `spring.datasource.username` as a property it does allow `spring-datasource-username`. When resolving the `spring.datasource.username` property it will thus simply return (always) the one from this propertysource. So using spring boot property names as keyvault names is propably not a good idea in the first place. You might want to prefix it per application and use explicit placeholders in your configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried deleting keys used by Application 1 and now both application fails ro start with incorrect user id.password error.

Spring Boot does not have any default logic to automatically pick specific key names for properties like `SPRING-DATASOURCE-USERNAME` and `SPRING-DATASOURCE-PASSWORD`. The property values are resolved based on the placeholders `${...}` in your configuration.

- If still the issues exist with Azure Key Vault and Spring Boot configurations, you can try an alternative approach by explicitly specifying the secret names directly in your `application.properties` or `application.yaml` files, rather than relying on Spring Boot property placeholders. This approach can help ensure that each application retrieves the correct secrets from Azure Key Vault.

`application.yaml` for **Application 1:**

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: <datasource url>
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    username: ${spring.datasource.username}
    password: ${spring.datasource.password}
  cloud:
    azure:
      keyvault:
        secret:
          spring.datasource.username: <Azure Key Vault secret name for username>
          spring.datasource.password: <Azure Key Vault secret name for password>
```

`application.yaml` for **Application 2:**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: <datasource url>
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    username: ${spring.datasource.username.app2}
    password: ${spring.datasource.password.app2}
  cloud:
    azure:
      keyvault:
        secret:
          spring.datasource.username.app2: <Azure Key Vault secret name for username for App2>
          spring.datasource.password.app2: <Azure Key Vault secret name for password for App2>
```